Netty IllegalStateException - SSLEngine already closed
We have server/client product where client connects to server over ssl. For this we are using netty framework 3.9.4.
There is no issue with few client connections. But observing below exception when trying to connect the client in thousands.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SSLEngine already closed
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:1074)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handleDownstream(SslHandler.java:623)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:784)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.writeRequested(SimpleChannelHandler.java:292)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleDownstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:254)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:704)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:671)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:248)
    at com.symantec.dlp.communications.transportlayer.impl.NettyTransportConnection$WriteOutboundDataTask.run(NettyTransportConnection.java:2126)
    at com.symantec.dlp.communications.transportlayer.impl.PrioritizedTaskQueue.run(PrioritizedTaskQueue.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

I searched for this error and it looks like observed by many. But I could not find if it is solved in any of the future releases.
Can someone help me to resolve this issue?
